# Switch to the main scene when back from background

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using cocos2d i am trying to switch back to the main scene where ever the user is back from background . the main scene is called `Home`

I have tried that without success :

```
-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application
{

    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
          //[director_ startAnimation]; //this one i took out
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Home node]];


}
```

what happen is that i can see that the `Home` scene was loaded- BY LOGS, but the view i can see is still another scene and not the `Home`

Whats the correct way to switch/replace/push back the main scene each time we back from background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the startAnimation back in and everything should be fine. Without startAnimation, cocos2d is still in the suspended state and won't do anything.

Comment: Thnanks but my problem is that the previous scene , has also a uiview so when i replace scene like you said, it does replace, but the previous uiview still there on top of the scene. i need a way to remove all current scenes and UIViews before replacing it, how would i do that ??

Comment: you can remove the uiview upon scene change by imlementing onExit and remove it there